# Update array of structs with new element while keeping order

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column, say `arr`, that's an array of structs, so something like this:

```sql
[STRUCT('foo' as name, 1 as t), STRUCT('bar' as name, 3 as t)]
```

I'm running a merge statement and I want to update `arr` with new elements but maintaining a sorted order by `t`.

My attempt is to unnest the source and target `arr`, sort it, then `ARRAY_AGG` the structs back. So something like this:

```sql
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
target.arr = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT(target.arr, source.arr)) ORDER BY timestamp ASC)
```

But this is giving the error `Unexpected keyword SELECT`.

Not sure what's wrong. Is it just the `MERGE` statement?

---

EDIT: the error I'm getting is actually `Correlated Subquery is unsupported in UPDATE clause`

Comment: provide the whole statement you have! just portion is not that helpful

Comment: I'm working on something very similar to this, where I am running an UPDATE and need to do a deep merge of an array of structs in target and source. I am also getting `Correlated Subquery is unsupported in UPDATE clause`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the answer. BigQuery currently don't support subqueries in `UPDATE` or `WHEN` statements.

Comment: doesn't mean you cannot achieve what is in the title of your question!